# Weighted union-find with path compression in Python 3

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x, graph, union-find

I implemented the [Union-Find data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure#Operations) and would love to receive some feedback about my code. I have just begun programming and welcome any feedback or constructive criticism which would improve my *code quality* and *professionalism*.

```
class UnionFind:

    def __init__(self, N=1001):
        self.N = N
        self.id = [i for i in range(self.N)]
        self._rank = [1] * self.N

    def __root(self, x):
        while x != self.id[self.id[x]]:
            self.id[x] = self.id[self.id[x]]
            x = self.id[x]
        return x

    def find(self, p, q):
        return self.__root(p) == self.__root(q)

    def unite(self, p, q):
        i = self.__root(p)
        j = self.__root(q)
        if self._rank[j] > self._rank[i]:
            i, j = j, i
        self.id[j] = i
        self._rank[i] += self._rank[j]
```

I was working on the problem of finding cycles in undirected graphs and realised union-find could be used to efficiently solve this problem and hence, implemented it.

In this instance the input would be a list of [u, v] pairs where u and v are integers and u < v. u and v are the node numbers of the graph under consideration.

For example the input [[1, 3], [2, 3], [1, 2]] would represent

[image]

**Finding cycles**

The idea is as follows

> iterate over the [u, v] pairs
>   if find(u, v): there exists a cycle since [u, v] belong to the same connected component
>   else: unite(u, v)

For the example graph [[1, 3], [2, 3], [1, 2]] above, the code would return on [1, 2] since adding this would result in a cycle.

Comment: Why does find in wikipedia have one argument but your implementation has two? "Find(x) follows the chain of parent pointers from x upwards through the tree until an element is reached whose parent is itself. This element is the root of the tree and is the representative member of the set to which x belongs, and may be x itself." What is the objective of this change?

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. As I have mentioned in the question, I wrote this code with the goal of finding cycles in the graph and hence the find took two parameters u,v where u and v represented the node numbers of the graph. Since this was problem specific I used the Wiki implementation as a reference, but now I have changed the signature so that the code sticks to the _original_ algorithm. Do have a look at the new version of the code. Thanks.

Comment: Please don't change the code after receiving an answer; [see faq](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Oh I'm sorry I was not aware of this. I'll keep this in mind moving forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you [Janne Karila](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/10916/janne-karila) and [Caridorc](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/54718/caridorc) for your suggestions.I have incorporated some of your changes into the code and this is the revised code. I welcome any further suggestions or improvements. Thank you for your time.

```
class UnionFind:

def __init__(self, N=1001):
    self.N = N
    self.parent = [i for i in range(self.N)]
    self._rank = [1] * self.N

def find(self, x):
    while x != self.parent[self.parent[x]]:
        self.parent[x] = self.parent[self.parent[x]]
        x = self.parent[x]
    return x

def unite(self, p, q):
    i = self.find(p)
    j = self.find(q)
    if i == j:
        return
    if self._rank[j] > self._rank[i]:
        i, j = j, i
    self.parent[j] = i
    self._rank[i] += self._rank[j]
```

Comment: In the `unite` function I'd use `if i != j: ...`. It would streamline the logic and remove extra `return` statement.

Answer (score 3):

- `unite` should check if `p` and `q` are in the same set already and do nothing in that case.
- Using dictionaries instead of lists as internal data structures would make this more flexible. Now the elements must be from `range(N)` and `N` has to be known at the start. Wikipedia suggests a MakeSet function which you could implement like this, and your other functions would continue to work unchanged:

  ```
  def __init__(self):
      self.id = {}
      self._rank = {}

  def make_set(self, element):
      self.id[element] = element
      self._rank[element] = 1
  ```
- `id` is a non-obvious name for a data structure stores the parent of each node in a tree. Why not `parent`?
- A single leading underscore is conventionally used to indicate private data.
- It is possible condense these two lines to one and avoid the extra lookup of `self.id[x]`

  ```
  self.id[x] = self.id[self.id[x]]
  x = self.id[x]
  ```

  with a chained assignment. However, you risk confusing a reader who is not well familiar with the order of evaluation. The right hand side is evaluated first, and the assignments are carried out starting from `self.id[x]` on the left, and the value of  `x` changes after:

  ```
  self.id[x] = x = self.id[self.id[x]]
  ```

Comment: I would avoid condensing the statements because it can be confusing because `x` appears in two parts. The OP way is simpler. The other points are good

Comment: @Caridorc Edited to point out the possible confusion. IMO the shorter version is easier to read, as long as you know how it works.

Comment: @JanneKarila Thanks a lot for your comments. I have taken into consideration a few of your suggestions like refactoring `unite` function, renaming `id` as `parent`.  
I was not clear what you meant when you said when you suggested to use dictionary  as the internal datastructure. Could you please elaborate on this?  
Also, regarding the assignment I feel `self.id[x] = x = self.id[self.id[x]]` is _less readable_ than `self.id[x] = self.id[self.id[x]]  
x = self.id[x]`  
(Of course YMMV)